# prevent Dist::Zilla from inserting the copyright year?

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

By default if [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla) finds no copyright year it will use the current year, since it doesn't seem to support multiple years or year ranges I find the current year to be most appropriate. However, whenever I run `dzil new Module` it automatically inserts the copyright year into my `dist.ini`. Is there a way to prevent Dist::Zilla from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [`[DistINI]`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aDistINI) from your minting profile, and use a template `dist.ini` file with [GatherDir::Template](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aGatherDir%3a%3aTemplate) instead.  That's much more flexible.

As an example, here's my `skel/dist.ini`:

```
;                                                       -*-conf-windows-*-{{
    $license = ref $dist->license;
    if ( $license =~ /^Software::License::(.+)$/ ) {
        $license = $1;
    } else {
        $license = "=$license";
    }

    $authors = join( "\n", map { "author  = $_" } @{$dist->authors} );
    '';
}}
name    = {{$dist->name}}
{{$authors}}
license = {{$license}}
copyright_holder = {{$dist->copyright_holder}}

[@Author::CJM / CJM]

[AutoPrereqs]
skip = ^(?:lib|strict|utf8|warnings)$
```

And then my `profile.ini` includes:

```
[GatherDir::Template]
root = skel
include_dotfiles = 1 ; want .gitignore
```

Comment: Exactly!  This is also what I would do.

Comment: it appears I did the templating too (in a long lost set of minters at home) ... except I didn't bother with funky logic, I just copied my license, copyright holder, etc. There doesn't really appear to be any advantage to not doing that.

Comment: @rjbs why can't be just make the `[DistINI]` plugin more configurable as to which sections to include, so logic like authors join, and license selection don't have to be in templates. Also why include `copyright_year` at all in the `[DistINI]` plugin given that it's completely optional in the config? seems like a bad default maybe.